# Using docker/build-push-action@v3 github action, a nested hidden folder isn't copied

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

I'm using github actions to do a build and push for an image to my google artifact registry.

There's a number of steps in the workflow, to condense it down to what's relevant...

```
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - name: Authenticate to google cloud
        uses: (external workflow... redacted...)

      - name: Download workspace data
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3 
        (this step pulls down a folder from a previous workflow, containing the .next folder)

      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          platforms: ${{ inputs.build_arm && 'linux/amd64,linux/arm64' || 'linux/amd64'}}
          tags: ${{ inputs.image_name }}:${{ inputs.image_tag }}
          build-args: |
            ${{secrets.build-args}}
            ${{inputs.build-args}}
          secrets: |
            ${{secrets.build-secrets}}
```

In the working directory (and docker context) for the build, there is a folder called `next` which contains another hidden folder called `.next`.

The Dockerfile has a step:

`COPY   next         /opt/auth-service/next`

**The problem**

My issue is, during the build-and-push stage, the COPY stage above copies all the contents of the `next` folder **apart from** the hidden folder and I can't seem to find out why.

**What I've tried**

I've used tmate (`mxschmitt/action-tmate@v3`) to SSH into the github action runner just before the build/push step and can confirm the folder `next/.next` is present. Whilst on the github runner I can also run `docker build -t <image-name> .` and then when I download that image to my laptop and run it - the next/.next folder is there. Just not when it's build by the `docker/build-push-action@v3` action.

Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Does the build work as expected locally via `docker build .` or similar?

Comment: @jcragun Yes it works as expected using docker build, and it works on the GitHub runner using the docker build command

Comment: Oh, interesting. No wonder it's hard to debug. I'm not sure what's going on, but I did read [the docs](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action) which says:

"Be careful because any file mutation in the steps that precede the build step will be ignored, including processing of the .dockerignore file since the context is based on the Git reference. However, you can use the Path context using the context input alongside the actions/checkout action to remove this restriction."

Comment: @jcragun ah that's interesting! Since my steps before my build down download an artifact from a previous build stage into this. So if I try using the context input this might resolve the issue.

Comment: @jcragun yep that's done it! Adding that all important `context: .` has done the trick and the .next folder is now in the image. Feel free to pop this on as an answer :)

Comment: Wow! Glad it worked. I edited my answer to include the correct info that actually fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action) for `docker/build-push-action@v3` says:

> Be careful because **any file mutation in the steps that precede the build step will be ignored, including processing of the `.dockerignore` file** since the context is based on the Git reference. However, you can use the [Path context](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#path-context) using the [`context` input](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#inputs) alongside the [`actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout/) action to remove this restriction.

You need to add the `context: .`:

```
jobs:
  docker:
    steps:
      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: .
```

Comment: I’ve checked both - it’s not in either

Comment: @sc-leeds try copying the hidden directory directly and see what happens - either it errors out or has unexpected results: `COPY next/.next /opt/auth-service/next/.next`.

Comment: I've tried that also (sorry I should have mentioned in original post), and it complains that the next/.next folder does not exist. Could this be permissions I wonder?